# Python read api , result to float

Tags: python

I want make program in python 2.7 to read api from www 
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XRPEUR

I was partly successful, but i need only first number .
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

xrp = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XRPEUR"

response = requests.get(xrp)
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
c = parsed["result"]["XXRPZEUR"]["c"]

print c

"""
print c =


[u'0.38310000', u'1564.04672409']


"""
```

My result is :

> [u'0.38310000', u'1564.04672409']

but i need only number 0.38310000.
Can you help me ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[u'0.38310000', u'1564.04672409']`
>
> Looks like you are dealing with a `list` as you can see it is in `[]`
>   brackets with comma delimited items. Lists are 0-index based, meaning
>   0 is the position of the first element.

`c[0]` will get you just the first number.

Then to convert to float, use `float()`

```
... code
some_string = c[0]
some_float = float(some_string)
```

Or, shorthand on a single line, assuming you always have at least one element in the response:

```
first_num = float(parsed["result"]["XXRPZEUR"]["c"][0])
```

**Edit:**

Going to leave the answer up, but I think I initially misunderstood your question and you need all the results (not only first one) as floats.

In this case, use `map()` to convert all of the elements of the list to floats (as per @LeKhan9's answer, who posted `map()` solution before me.

```
c = parsed["result"]["XXRPZEUR"]["c"]
result = map(float, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you question is how to convert this list to a list of floats:

```
c = map(float, c)
print c
```

output:

```
[0.3831, 1564.04672409]
```

you can then get the first float through `c[0]`

Comment: quick and easy answer from both. Thank you  Dmitry and Lekhan..... c[0] is magic word! :)